# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen “Ermittlung” und “Ermittelung”?

Tags: difference

Ich habe eine Frage über das Wort *Ermittlung.* Ich hatte einen Roman geschrieben und das Wort *Ermittlung* gesucht, um zu bestätigen, dass ich es korrekt geschrieben habe. Damals habe ich aus Versehen *Ermitt**e**lung* in Dict.cc gesucht und folgenden, seltsamen Beitrag gefunden:

> Ermittelung (f) – ascertainment

Aber *Ermittlung* hat diese Bedeutung auch (neben vielen anderen)! Deswegen möchte ich danach fragen, welches Wort für die folgende Bedeutung ("ascertainment") zu benutzen ist, *Ermittelung* oder *Ermittlung?* Oder haben beide die gleiche Bedeutung? Oder ist *Ermittelung* falsch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im Duden gibt es das Wort Ermittelung nicht, sondern nur [Ermittlung](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Ermittlung).
Trotzdem ist diese Schreibweise auch vorzufinden, siehe auch [hier](http://www.dwds.de/cache/shortcuts/Ermittelung.html), vielleicht weil das Verb "ermitteln" heißt und daher häufig falsch geschrieben wird. Ich kann mir aber auch vorstellen, dass diese Schreibweise früher einmal gültig war.
Von daher gehe ich davon aus, dass beide Wörter das Gleiche bedeuten und Ermittlung die heute richtige Schreibweise ist.

Comment: Ja, vielleicht die Ermittelung war einmal gültig aber nicht jetzt. Vielen Dank.

Comment: Hm, die "Ermittelung der Daten" klingt für mich gar nicht so falsch... Aber "Ermittlung" ist wohl schon die modernere Version, und wenn es um Polizeiarbeit geht wohl auch ausschließlich gebraucht.

Comment: In **"Der Große Duden"** vom VEB Bibliographischen Institut Leipzig, **1987** herausgegeben, steht sinngemäß das Folgende (hier gekürzt): Auslassung _kann_ eintreten bei Substantiven auf -ung, die von Verben auf -eln abgeleitet sind. Manchmal ist die Form ohne e die übliche. Beispiele: Handlung, Wandlung, Entwicklung, Vermittlung. Manchmal ist die Form mit e die übliche. Beispiele: Entwässerung, Verbesserung. **Zusammenfassung:** Es war einmal Kannbestimmung, Ermittlung war und ist jedoch definitiv üblicher.